# Hiding hardware button of Android Devices

Tags: android

my mobile device(Xperia TX) have three Buttons.

Now , Is it possible to hide the mobile's buttons? (**Buttons in white border in below image**) :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code in your onCreate() method :

```
    View bView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    bView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```